# If I buy XCode 4 on the app store, can I do iOS development?

Tags: xcode, ios

I want to get into iOS development, and I didn't know if I NEED to do the $99/year registration just to play around with the SDK and XCode 4. I know you need that to submit apps to the store, but if I just want to do my own personal programming, can I just buy XCode? Thanks guys, it is just that $99 is a big step to play around with something I might end up not pursuing that much.

Answer (score 7):

You can buy Xcode, but you'll be limited to development in the iOS simulator. The $99 fee is required to install on actual devices for testing.

Comment: Do note that the iOS simulator tries to be as close as possible, but it's not a perfect copy of iOS. There will likely be some bugs when you move to developing on the device that weren't present in the simulator, and it'll run significantly slower in real situations. Good to start with, though.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If I ever get to the point where I would actually want to deploy an application to devices, the $99 would be no problem.